# mysql performance issues

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

i have a simple query with no joins that is running very slow (20s+). The table queried has about 400k rows and all columns used in the where clause are indexed.

```
SELECT deals.id, deals.title, 
       deals.amount_sold * deals.sale_price   AS total_sold_total
FROM deals  
WHERE deals.country_id = 33 
  AND deals.target_approved = 1 
  AND deals.target_active = 1 
  AND deals.finished_at >= '2012-04-01' 
  AND deals.started_at <= '2012-04-30'
ORDER BY total_sold_total DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Im struggling with this since last week, please i could use some help :)

Update 1

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  deals   index_merge NewIndex3,finished_at_index,index_deals_on_country_id,index_deals_on_target_active,index_deals_on_target_approved   index_deals_on_target_active,index_deals_on_target_approved,index_deals_on_country_id   2,2,5   \N  32382   Using intersect(index_deals_on_target_active,index_deals_on_target_approved,index_deals_on_country_id); Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: Please post the result of EXPLAIN.

Comment: You have indexes on all cols in the WHERE clause, but your bottleneck is probably ordering on the calculated `total_sold_total`

Comment: MySQL will only use a single index per query, having indexes on all those columns may just be bloating your index files. Unless they're being used in other queries.

Comment: @KingIsaac, take a look at the [Index Merge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html) optimization. Unfortunately, we can't make simple statements like "MySQL will only use a single index per query" any more.

Comment: Can you try running the query without the indexes?  I'd be curious if that ran faster.

Comment: I don't know MySQL very well, but since the WHERE clause only uses `AND`s, shouldn't it be able to do multiple index scans and build a bitmap?

Comment: ORDER BY total_sold_told would hurt the performance

Comment: How many rows are being returned?

Answer (score 3):

To improve the selection, create the following compound indexes, using the columns in the WHERE clause, in the order specified:

```
(country_id, target_approved, target_active, finished_at)
(country_id, target_approved, target_active, started_at)
```

You want columns with higher cardinality first, with ranges last. MySQL cannot [utilize any key parts past the first range](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-multi-part), which is why we have two separate indexes that diverge at the range in the WHERE clause (`>=` and `<=`).

If MySQL doesn't utilize both indexes through an index merge, then you might consider deleting one of them.

Unfortunately, MySQL still has to return all of the rows, computing the total_sold_total, before it can order the rows. In other words, MySQL has to manually sort the rows after it has retrieved the entire dataset.

The time it takes to sort will be directly proportional to the size of the result set.

LIMIT optimizations cannot be used because LIMIT is applied after the sort.

Unfortunately, having ranges in your WHERE clause precludes you from adding a precalculated total_sold_total column to the end of your index to return the results already in order, which would prevent the manual sort.